# Why do we not care about target class probabilities of 0 in the cross entropy equation?

Tags: neural-networks, entropy

Only the target classes where probability is equal to 1 contributes to the loss.

I'm dealing specifically with neural networks, but the question is general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, we care about it, but it is hidden in the case of soft-max. If each unit's activation function only depends on its pre-activation value as in basic sigmoid neurons

$ L = - \sum y.*log(h_{(\theta)}(x^{(i)})) + (1-y).* log(1-h_{(\theta)}(x^{(i)})) $

where '.*' is element-wise product, 'y' is ground truth, and $h_{(\theta)}(x^{(i)})$ is activations from the last layer

The second term in above equation is used to pull probabilities of wrong classes to '0'.

However, if you are using soft-max activation function, each unit's output depends on all pre-activations on the same layer.

$ softmax(z_{(j)}) =  \frac{exp(z_{(j)})}{\sum_k  exp(z_{(k)})}$

As a result, increasing probability of true class, decreases probabilities of the wrong classes. So, you don't need to include a term which decreases probabilities of the wrong classes to objective function.

Comment: I see (I think). For the softmax, it's hidden under the normalization term. Also what do you mean by "props" and ".∗"?

Comment: @Anonymous the answer is edited